# What is the difference between [exact-duplicates] and [duplicate-questions] tags? - synonym request

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

What is the difference between [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates) (16 questions) and [duplicate-questions](/questions/tagged/duplicate-questions) (4 questions) tags?

As of now, neither of above have tag wiki; per my reading of handful of questions I randomly picked these look like having the same meaning.

---

Please consider merging mentioned tags, and making them synonyms.

Comment: Done. Merged, synonym created.

Comment: And I got a badge for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those two look like they should be merged. I propose we make [duplicate-questions](/questions/tagged/duplicate-questions) the master tag, it might have less questions but it's a better tag than [exact-duplicates](/questions/tagged/exact-duplicates).

Comment: your preference for master tag makes good sense to me, given **[recent guidance at MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773)**: _'we want to tell the user ...something like, “*Somebody already asked this. If that other question doesn't solve your problem, please clarify your question to explain how it's different.*” ...No argument about how exact an "exact duplicate" needs to be...'_